# Resizing an NSView smaller than its subviews?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Couldn't find anything on the net about this and wondered if anyone on SO has a solution.

I have an NSView with several subviews that are centered by removing the left and right anchor points. When I resize my view, programatically or with the mouse, to a smaller width than the subviews: it pushes them off center. Has anyone come across this before and do you have a solution?

**EDIT**: I want to be able to resize my view to a zero width. The reason being, the view is actually part of a split view and I have hooked up a button to 'collapse' it. When it collapses all of the subviews are pushed off-center and aren't re-centered when the view is resized, effectively un-collapsing it.

Comment: Why would you want a parent view to be smaller than its subviews? Just make it encompass them all in size, and you'll be fine.

Comment: I've updated the question to explain why I want to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem now and thought I would share incase anyone comes across this issue in the future.

No amount of playing with autosizing options or view layouts in Interface Builder seemed to stop my subviews from getting moved off center. I did manage to find this link [here](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/67127-how-to-keep-subview-centered-autoresizing.html) and from this page, the advice:

> Springs and struts, as currently
>   implemented, are really no good for
>   anything but keeping either one or
>   both sides of a view "stuck" to the
>   nearest edge.  Any sort of centering
>   behavior, division of gained/lost area
>   between multiple views, etc. has to be
>   done by hand.

Based on this I overrode my view's `setFrame:` method and manually laid out my subviews using their `setFrame:` method. This works great and gives me the results I'm looking for.

Comment: Do not do this in -drawRect:. Override -setFrame: and/or -setFrameSize:, call super, then call your tile routine. -drawRect: is meant to be fast and lightweight and you're not meant to perform subview tiling in it.

Comment: Just pulled up the relevant code and I do indeed override setFrame as suggested. Must have changed it since posting this answer. Changed my answer to reflect better advice.

Answer (score 0):

There is the same issue using NSSplitView, resizing here one Subview  to be smaller than the Subview Subviews makes sense,e.g. having small charts in the upper subview, and an rss reader in the lower subview.

If you want to show only the rss reader in the lower subview, you can "hide" the upper subview, but after resizing the upper subview the NSImageView are not layed out the same as in the beginning. Check this nib/[xCode Project](http://www.wuala.com/Fahrenberg/Public/SplitViewSimple/) and the following [screenshot](http://www.wuala.com/Fahrenberg/Public/splitview%20example.tiff/) to see this behaviour.

Only workaroung is to override the resize function to stop getting smaller.